# WebAssembly Link Error: import object field 'DYNAMICTOP_PTR' is not a Number

Tags: javascript, emscripten, webassembly

The following C file is compiled to wasm with emscripten:

```
int counter = 100;

int count() {
    counter += 1;
    return counter;
}
```

```sh
$ emcc counter.c -o counter.wasm -s WASM=1 -s SIDE_MODULE=1
```

With no issues. I then have webpack loading the wasm file (with [wasm-loader](https://github.com/ballercat/wasm-loader)) as an UInt8Array:

```
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(648);
var uint8 = new Uint8Array(buffer);
uint8.set([0,97,115,109,1,0,0,0,0,12,6,100,121,108,105,110,107,144,128,192,2,0,1,150,128,128,128,0,5,96,1,127,0,96,1,127,1,127,96,0,1,127,96,2,127,127,0,96,0,0,2,179,129,128,128,0,10,3,101,110,118,14,68,89,78,65,77,73,67,84,79,80,95,80,84,82,3,127,0,3,101,110,118,13,116,101,109,112,68,111,117,98,108,101,80,116,114,3,127,0,3,101,110,118,5,65,66,79,82,84,3,127,0,3,101,110,118,10,109,101,109,111,114,121,66,97,115,101,3,127,0,3,101,110,118,9,116,97,98,108,101,66,97,115,101,3,127,0,6,103,108,111,98,97,108,3,78,97,78,3,124,0,6,103,108,111,98,97,108,8,73,110,102,105,110,105,116,121,3,124,0,3,101,110,118,18,97,98,111,114,116,83,116,97,99,107,79,118,101,114,102,108,111,119,0,0,3,101,110,118,6,109,101,109,111,114,121,2,0,128,2,3,101,110,118,5,116,97,98,108,101,1,112,0,0,3,137,128,128,128,0,8,1,2,0,3,3,2,4,4,6,242,128,128,128,0,20,127,1,35,0,11,127,1,35,1,11,127,1,35,2,11,127,1,65,0,11,127,1,65,0,11,127,1,65,0,11,127,1,65,0,11,127,1,65,0,11,127,1,65,0,11,124,1,35,5,11,124,1,35,6,11,127,1,65,0,11,127,1,65,0,11,127,1,65,0,11,127,1,65,0,11,124,1,68,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11,127,1,65,0,11,125,1,67,0,0,0,0,11,125,1,67,0,0,0,0,11,127,0,65,0,11,7,184,128,128,128,0,4,6,95,99,111,117,110,116,0,6,18,95,95,112,111,115,116,95,105,110,115,116,97,110,116,105,97,116,101,0,8,11,114,117,110,80,111,115,116,83,101,116,115,0,7,8,95,99,111,117,110,116,101,114,3,26,9,129,128,128,128,0,0,10,190,129,128,128,0,8,173,128,128,128,0,1,1,127,2,64,35,10,33,1,35,10,32,0,106,36,10,35,10,65,15,106,65,112,113,36,10,35,10,35,11,78,4,64,32,0,16,0,11,32,1,15,0,11,0,11,133,128,128,128,0,0,35,10,15,11,134,128,128,128,0,0,32,0,36,10,11,141,128,128,128,0,0,2,64,32,0,36,10,32,1,36,11,11,11,146,128,128,128,0,0,35,12,65,0,70,4,64,32,0,36,12,32,1,36,13,11,11,161,128,128,128,0,1,4,127,2,64,35,10,33,3,35,3,65,0,106,40,2,0,33,0,32,0,65,1,106,33,1,32,1,15,0,11,0,11,133,128,128,128,0,1,1,127,1,11,152,128,128,128,0,0,2,64,35,3,65,16,106,36,10,35,10,65,128,128,192,2,106,36,11,16,7,11,11,11,135,128,128,128,0,1,0,35,3,11,1,100,]);
```

My JS code then call the following:

```
import Counter from './wasm/counter'
const counter = new Counter();
```

And fails on the instantiation with the following Error:

```
LinkError: import object field 'DYNAMICTOP_PTR' is not a Number
```

wasm-loader uses the following default options (importObject) for `WebAssembly.Instance(module, importObject)`:

```
{
  'global': {},
  'env': {
    'memory': new Memory({initial: 10, limit: 100}),
    'table': new Table({initial: 0, element: 'anyfunc'})
  }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong ? How can I successfully load the wasm code ?

**Edit:**
Following @Ghillie advice I tried to compile the C code with different optimization flags:

`-O1`, `-02`, `-O3`, `-Os` and `-Oz`  throw a `LinkError: import object field 'memoryBase' is not a Number` which is a different error but doesn't solve the issue.

**Edit 2:**

Solely adding the `-O1` optimization flag didn't work but having a different error message allowed to debug the code so both @Ghillie and my answer offer the complete solution to my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Compile with any optimization flag other than the default `-O0`.  For example:

`emcc counter.c -O1 -o counter.wasm -s WASM=1 -s SIDE_MODULE=1`

The various optimization flags are listed here:

https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/optimizing/Optimizing-Code.html

Comment: Thanks for the advice but unfortunately it doesn't work, see my edit for the details.

Comment: Actually it helped as having a different LinkError allowed me to debug the code, cf. my answer, thanks ! :)

Answer (score 8):

The solution appeared to be to tweak the `importObject` used in `WebAssembly.Instance(module, importObject)`:

```
{
  'env': {
    'memoryBase': 0,
    'tableBase': 0,
    'memory': new WebAssembly.Memory({initial: 256}),
    'table': new WebAssembly.Table({initial: 0, element: 'anyfunc'})
  }
}
```

`memoryBase` and `tableBase` were needed and the initial memory value was too low (throwed a `LinkedError: Memory of incompatible size`).

Also I had to call `counter.exports._count()` and not `counter.exports.count()` once the instantiation was done.

Also thanks to @Ghillie as the `-O1` optimization flag was indeed needed.

*Edit: if you are reading this and just getting started with WebAssembly, I made a summary of my first experience, in case it helps: **[WebAssembly 101: a developer's first steps](https://blog.openbloc.fr/webassembly-first-steps/)***.

Comment: `memoryBase` and `tableVase` are required because you are compiling as a side module.  You can read a bit more [here](https://github.com/WebAssembly/tool-conventions/blob/master/DynamicLinking.md) if you haven't seen it yet.